# Parse JSON string in SQL

Tags: sql, json, parsing, hive

I have a column of JSON strings in my SQL table. I want to extract the 'page' value, any idea how?
{"action.type":"click","page":1424}

Comment: Just got a pure SQL version working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive actually has a command just for that [get_json_object](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-getjsonobject)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure SQL version.

```
DECLARE @json varchar(64);
DECLARE @index int;
SELECT @json = '{"action.type":"click","page":1424}';
DECLARE @length int = LEN(@json);
DECLARE @pageIndex int = CHARINDEX('page":', @json);
DECLARE @difference int = @length - (@pageIndex + 6); -- 6 is for page":
SELECT @index =  CHARINDEX('page', @json);
SELECT SUBSTRING(@json, @index + 6, @difference);
```

This will give you a result of `1424`

It is really long-winded, but it shows step-by-step how it get's that value. You can easily refactor that into a stored procedure.